# "WatchKit: Duplicate call. Discarding call for InterfaceController" notice when calling openParentApplication

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

In my watch app's main interface controller's `willActivate`, I am sending a request to the parent app by calling `openParentApplication:reply:`. I have noticed that, quite often the request doesn't get sent out to the parent app, but instead the following notice shows up in the console:

`My App WatchKit Extension[2894] <Notice>: (Note ) WatchKit: WatchKit: Duplicate call. Discarding call for InterfaceController key=1 property= value=circle value class=__NSCFConstantString`

Does anyone know what could be causing this? What exactly is this call a duplicate of? I MUST ask the parent app for some info upon opening the app (when this main interface is shown), how can I make it so that it does not discard my request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting the same, did you find a solution?